# Git which branch has modified?

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to create a git hook script which is trigger a Jenkins job and job update the local repo. I want to pass the modified branch name as parameter because I don't want update whole project repo on the Jenkins instance.

So what I want to know is how can i determinate that which branch changed in a git repo. (git command)

I realley appraciate any idea.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you explain it in more detail?

Answer (score -1):

1. Setup a parameterised jenkins job to accept branch name as parameter and do what you with that branch name
2. Use update hook on server side in the central repository. Run following from inside the hook
   `curl -X POST '<server URL>/job/<JOB NAME>/buildWithParameters?branchName=${1}` where ${1} will be the branch name

Comment: Yeah I already know that. What I asking is the git part. So how can I determinate that which branch is modified?

Comment: The first parameter passed to the update hook by git is the name of the modified branch.

Comment: Here is the sample

`case "$1" in

  refs/tags/*)
    <This is for tags>
    ;;
  refs/heads/*)
    <run your curl command here>
 
    ;;
  *)
    deny >/dev/null \
    "<Do something>"
    ;;
esac`